# Vs update result in System.TypeLoadException

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, typeloadexception

I am developping a windows phone 8.1 sdk
**When I use vs 2013 update 3,the code works** and i can run my demo.
but,yesterday,**I update my vs 2013 to update 4,then throw a System.TypeLoadException**
code details below:

```
var swapChainPanel = new SwapChainPanel();
Children.Add(swapChainPanel);
var res = new CXMapResource("", "");
cxEngine = new CXMapEngine(res);
```

Type **CXMapResource** is a windows runtime component type written by c++
and it is **the first winrt type** I load in my code
I set a break point before this line,it goes here,and then continue,then crash,
output:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in Com.AMap.winmd
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in WP8.1Demo.ni.EXE
```

**Update at 2014 11 18 16：08**

[image]

```
System.TypeLoadException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233054
  Message=Requested Windows Runtime type 'WinRTDXMapLib.CXMapResource' is not registered.
  Source=mscorlib
  TypeName=WinRTDXMapLib.CXMapResource
  StackTrace:
       at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)
       at WinRTDXMapLib.CXMapResource..ctor(String EngineResourcePath, String ShaderResourcePath)
       at Com.AMap.Maps.Core.AmapSharpEngine..ctor()
       at Com.AMap.Api.Maps.AMapControl..ctor()
       at WP8._1Demo.MainPage..ctor()
       at WP8._1Demo.WP8_1Demo_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_0_MainPage()
       at WP8._1Demo.WP8_1Demo_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
  InnerException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
       HResult=-2147221164
       Message=Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
       ErrorCode=-2147221164
       InnerException:
```

I let my college **run the same code in vs 2013 update 2**,and it works
please tell me what might result in this problem,give me some advice,Thanks!!

---

> It works now!

[VS 2013 UPDATE5 CTP2](http://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2013-update5-vs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately we have the same problem with Update 4, this is probaly caused by referencing a winmd (C++) component.
We have the problem with the SmoothStreaming SDK for Windows 8.1.

We have reached to Microsoft but no answer yet.

A colleague solved this problem by reinstalling Windows and Visual Studio. Then he updated to Update 3. (Just removing the update 4 didn't work for him)
I rather avoid this 'solution' but if there is no hotfix next week, I probaly have to do these steps.

Update

Microsoft answered my issue that they will fix this problem in Update 5. 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1036072

Comment: finally I reinstall my vs 2013，Thank you for answering.And I also contact with Microsoft,hope it will be solved soon

Comment: I have the same problem, using a 3rd party lib in my Windows Store App project. was working with Update 3.

Comment: I restored my windows to the restore point created before I installed the Update 4, and all works fine now.

Comment: @terry could u find a way of using the original source in vs2013u4? What is the reason to result in the problem?

Comment: @Mark Hijdra could u find a way of using the original source in vs2013u4? What is the reason to result in the problem?

Comment: @IloveIniesta, Sorry, I haven't heard anything from M$. I am still running on Update 3. If you can't wait, just restore to Update 3. The worst case I know is like Mark Hijdra's answer.

Comment: @IloveIniesta I reinstalled Visual Studio and updated to Update 3, because I got no response from Microsoft. I have no idea why this problem occurs. I'll keep using vs2013u3 because it just works. Next update I'll be more cautious and first test it on a machine we barely use.

Comment: @terry thanks for reply.It seems that I can reproduce this problem,and am contacting Microsoft now,you can see my answer below

Comment: @Mark Hijdra thanks for reply.It seems that I can reproduce this problem,and am contacting Microsoft now,you can see my answer below

Comment: @MarkHijdra glad to know this will be fixed in the next update.

Comment: @terry will be fixed in next update? vs2015?Could u tell me how you know it ?Thanks

Comment: @terry I didn't notice the answer is updated.It is nice to see the progress

Comment: glad to see the progress,happy

Comment: @IloveIniesta The next update for VS2013. VS2015 had the same problem, I hope (and think) they will fix that either.

Comment: @MarkHijdra yes,the version of vs15 is just preview,so sure it'll be fixed in Rtm

Comment: IT IS OK NOW! o(∩_∩)o

Answer (score 0):

**Discussion about this problem:**

[Vs update result in System.TypeLoadException,was it a bug of VS?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d6313448-0d91-4a5d-ae1a-351b4b61bd2f/vs-update-result-in-systemtypeloadexceptionwas-it-a-bug-of-vs?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

[VS2013 Update 4: TypeLoad Exception when referencing a winmd (C++) component](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/347a88e2-ba88-4ccd-a397-784b1c8802ef/vs2013-update-4-typeload-exception-when-referencing-a-winmd-c-component?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

[Connect: TypeLoadException when referencing a winmd C++ component](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1036072)

I am able to reproduce this problem at Connect:

> **you can't create a constructor with param in c++ winrt component**

*****you can see my demo project here(attachment):*****
[Vs update result in System.TypeLoadException](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1081441/vs-update-result-in-system-typeloadexception#)