# Getting TypeLoadException when using Sqlite-WinRT

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

i am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app (WinRT) and i want to add support for SQLite. I have added the SQLite for Windows Phone extension to the project and also added the [SQLite-WinRT](http://sqlwinrt.codeplex.com/) wrapper. I also changed the build configuration to x86 so it can run in the emulator. 
My problem is: When i try to open a connection to a database file (either create or just open) i get a TypeLoadException.
My code to open the connection is like this:

```
using (var db = new SQLiteWinRT.Database(ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder, "Database.db"))
        {
            await db.OpenAsync(SqliteOpenMode.OpenOrCreateReadWrite);
            await db.ExecuteStatementAsync(@"create table if not exists MyTable ( ID integer not null primary key autoincrement, Name varchar(150) not null);");

            await db.ExecuteStatementAsync(@"insert into MyTable (Name) values ('Rafael');");
        }
```

When the first line is executed i get this error:

[image]

Here is a list of references in my project:

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: possibly related: [Vs update result in System.TypeLoadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965647/vs-update-result-in-system-typeloadexception)

Comment: This is interesting, i have VS2013 Update 4 too. But re-installing Windows and VS is not feasible. Also waiting for Update 5 is not feasible either since the project can't move forward without the database code. Also using other wrappers like SQLite-Net is not good for me because it is an ORM and i have to create classes that map to tables which is not a good solution for the database relations that i have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i managed to fix this issue. It appears it was caused by the Visual Studio IDE not registering WinMD types and causes the TypeLoadException at Runtime. 
Downloading [Visual Studio Update 5 RC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=46848%20%22Visual%20Studio%20Update%205%20RC) (Release Candidate) will fix the issue. Updating the IDE to Update 5 should take around 30 minutes depending on your internet speed.
The RC version is very stable and it is working as it should so i don't believe it will cause any issues with your current projects.